# Код на отслеживание автозапуска для Delphi7

Tags: delphi, реестр, delphi-7, автозагрузка

Пожалуйста, дайте код для отслеживания автозапуска. То есть чтобы вычислялась информация и сравнивалась, а при обнаружении изменений появлялось предупреждение.

Answer (score 3):

А в чем проблема то?

- получаем список задач в автозагрузке. 1, [2](http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=144053) и так далее.
- если нет сохраненного списка - сохраняем текущий. больше работы нет
- если есть предыдущий, то нужно сравнивать. Вот сходу [находиться пример](http://www.delphisources.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=12647). [Ещё](http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread349174.html). Если ожидается, что списки будут большие, то можно отсортировать списки и пройтись по ним.

Все, пол программы готово.
Осталось решить, когда запускать. Самый простой вариант - при старте и раз-два в час. Вариант посложнее - мониторить реестр. Одно с ключевых слов - RegNotifyChangeKeyValue.  Некоторые размышления [здесь](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/delphi/774721.all).

А дальше - дерзайте.